# get last element of a list of object based on created date

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have a list of Market__history that track the changes in my custom object market__c
Since I am manipulating a lot this object instead of making multiple SOQL call
I made one big SOQL call to extract ALL the history data for my specific markets ans now I can manipulate the data without calling too much time the servers.

What I would like to acheive is extract that LAST CREATED history object for each market but I am not sure how to acheive that.. I tried [-1] like in python without success

any idea ???

My code look the following;

1. extract all history data :

   List<Market__History> MarketHistory = [SELECT id, ParentId, OldValue, NewValue, Field, CreatedById, CreatedDate FROM Market__History where ParentId IN :RelevantMarketData];

2)looping my market and get the history data:

```
for(Market__c marketItem: RelevantMarketData ){
List<Market__History> MarketHistoryList = new List<Market__History>();
            for(Market__History marketHistoryItem: MarketHistory){
                if(marketHistoryItem.parentId == marketItem.id && marketHistoryItem.CreatedDate >= begDate && marketHistoryItem.CreatedDate >= endDate ){
                    MarketHistoryList.add(marketHistoryItem);
                }                
            }
            if(MarketHistoryList.size()>=1){
                //system.debug('test');
                system.debug('test: ' + MarketHistoryList.last());
                    
                } 
        }
```

Comment: Could you please explain in detail because you are talking about all changes to  history objects are specifically one. You can use order by with desc createddate like that

Answer (score 1):

In the History table, `CreatedDate` field is when the change was made Order your query by `CreatedDate`

```
List<Market__History> MarketHistory = [SELECT id, ParentId, OldValue, 
NewValue, Field, CreatedById, CreatedDate FROM Market__History where 
ParentId IN :RelevantMarketData order by CreatedDate desc];
```

Then the first item in your list will be the most recently created history record.

```
MarketHistory.get(0);
```